# Writing a loop that includes all but one of the variables in the sequence

Tags: r

Below I have my code. I'm

```
for (i in c(01,02,04,05,06,08,09,10,11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,53,54,55,56)) {
  for (j in 1978:2013) {
    for (k in vector) {
  dataprep.EM<-dataprep(
  foo=FinalCPS2,
  predictors=c("A1","A2","A3","FE","IND1","IND2","IND3","IND4","IND5","ED1","ED2"),
  special.predictors = list(list("EMP",1977:1981,c("mean"))),
  dependent = "EMP",
  unit.variable = "STATEFIP",
  time.variable = "YEAR",
  treatment.identifier = i,
  controls.identifier = k,
  time.predictors.prior = c(1977:j),
  time.optimize.ssr = c(1977:j),
  time.plot = c(1977:2015))
}}}
```

For the last variable I'm looking to have it fill in the entire sequence of number in the first variable, but to exclude one. The idea being to not include the same number that is being plugged in for 'i'. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you store the whole vectors in a variable (say `vec`), then use `setdiff(vec, i)` to get all *except* the `i` value. As an example: `vec <- 1:10; i <- 2L; setdiff(vec, i)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
controls.identifier = k[k!=i]
```

Which would then use all control identifiers not included as a treatment identifier.

You might face other problems though, your loop will write over `dataprep.EM` with each new iteration.

Edit: Also, if you output a new dataprep object for that many combinations of years and treatment identifier, doing `synth` on all that with that many predictors might take a while! If what you're aiming for is a country placebo test and a time placebo test you might want to do those iterations separately.